# Why destructor is calling?

Tags: c++, oop, destructor

I have a simple code.

```
#include <iostream>

struct BABE
{
    std::string* babe = nullptr;

    BABE(const char* str)
    {
        babe = new std::string(str);
    }
    ~BABE()
    {
        delete babe;
    }
};

int main()
{
    BABE bomb = "hello";
    bomb = "world";
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When Im trying to

```
bomb = "world";
```

it assign well, but then destructor is calling.

Why is it happening?

---

[image: bbb]

Comment: your class/struct is violating the rule of 3/5/0 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: What do you think the assignment `bomb = "world"` will do?

Comment: Tip: Don't use pointers, and avoid `new` whenever possible. Each allocation creates a number of *obligations you must fulfill* or suffer from a myriad of undefined behaviour bugs.

Comment: *Why is it happening?* -- If you did `std::cout << "Destroying: " << this << "\n";` in the destructor, you may see that you are destroying different `BABE` objects.  Then ask yourself where those objects came from.

Comment: Often printing out the address of the object in the destructor can help illuminate the issue. For example, if you also print the address in the constructors, you can play the matching game and see who got deleted when or iff you're accidentally calling a constructor you DIDN'T instrument or implement.

Comment: There is rarely a good reason to dynamically allocate a `std::string`. If you made it `std::string babe;` then the rule of 0 would apply and you would not have to worry about memory allocation or the more complicated rules of 3 or 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is it happening?

Because in this line:

```
bomb = "world";
```

To assign a `const char *` to your class, a temporary of struct `BABE` is created, that temporary is assigned to `bomb` (using the compiler-generated assignment operator), and then that temporary is destructed.

As you violated the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), the assignment leads to a disaster - a memory leak and a double-deletion of the same pointer.